# how to run url in background in ubuntu from putty?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, putty

I have one file test.php,  I want to run this file in backgroun in ubuntu server, I need command for that so i can do that process with putty, If i will close putty, then also it should have to run from background,Can anyone please help me for that ?

Answer (score 0):

try to run with & at the end

php script.php &

it will launch script in background

Comment: If i will shutdown my laptop then still it will work in background ?

Comment: Yes, it will be run as process in backgroud. You must kill process to stop script.